# Is accepting an answer a good idea?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I feel like letting the answer with most up-votes to be the top answer so if at any later time someone provides a better answer it could be replaced.

Comment: You decide for acceptance on your own, not what the community thinks. Don't be a sheep, or go with them just for reasonings to _save _ your question. You even might leave it with any unaccepted answers, unless you are eager about that 2 rep points.

Answer (score 3):

If a better answer comes up later, who's to say an even better one won't come up even later?

The argument of "maybe a better one will come up later" makes the assumption that there *will* be another, better answer. This doesn't always happen.

And if it does - the OP can always change the accepted answer to the better one.

In other words - if there is a good answer there, and it is the best answer from the set of answers, accept it. You can always change your mind later, if a better answer comes along.

---

Accepting an answer means "this answer worked best for me" (or is supposed to mean that - doesn't always happen). If that's the case, you should accept that answer.

Comment: Might be worth to drop a word about _"panic accepts"_, as I've been seeing done a lot on massively downvoted questions which received an answer. It seems some (particularly new) users think accepting an answer, may help to stop their question getting downvoted. I have the feeling that's a common pattern to be observed for new/not so well informed users (calling that _panic accept_ as mentioned).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - might have more to do with the +2 rep one gets for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are two different things.

The top voted answer is the one that the community thinks it is the best one. This doesn't mean that it is the one you may want to pursue. Maybe the overhead is to great, maybe you need something simpler, maybe you don't have the required time...

For these reason you as the question creator can specify a different "accepted" answer, the one that worked out for you. It may not be the best, you are just certifying that it worked with your constraints.

Also, consider that at any time you can unmark your old accepted answer and mark a new one if you deem it appropriate. Yes, it is a little bad for the original poster, but it is still a feature you should use.